# Facebook like button on a product page

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

My requirement is to integrate my client webpage and facebook using the Flike button. 
I have an html page which is used for all the products. Based on the product code selected, the content in the page changes. The URL format is something like this - 
in the browser it shows : http://xyz.com/product.aspx,
in the view source, in the `action` attribute of the `form` tag : `../../product.aspx?prdcode=123&amp;catcode=3453`

Now, my requirement is to place an flike button on this page. I have tried doing it in several ways... but the issue is:

If I click on flike button on one page.. the button is disabled for every other product.
Not sure what all needs to be included in to get this functionality right.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you're so we can inspect it?

Comment: <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://xyz.com&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Answer (score 3):

For a product listing page you'd need to have multiple like buttons, each pointing at a URL which represents an individual product - each of those pages needs the appropriate open graph meta tags, include the JS SDK once on your listing page, and have multiple `<fb:like` tags pointing at the individual product URLs

If the page content is dynamic, I think you can do the same, but you'll need to remove and add the like button as the content changes

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I will try the same and let you know.

Comment: Hi, 
I used the below code and i am able to fetch the current url value properly 

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type= "text/javascript">
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement(s);js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<fb:like href="" send="false" width="400"  layout="button_count" show_faces="true"></fb:like>